# How to rosmake project with c and cpp?

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am making a project with c and cpp involved. For example, in the src folder I have:

> a.h a.cpp -- main function
>
> b.h b.c -- some utility functions

How can I modified the **CMakeList.txt** to make it work? I get errors saying that **a.cpp** has undefined reference to some functions, which are defined in **b.c**, while I already include **b.h** in **a.h**. My current **CMakeList.txt** looks like this.

```
rosbuild_add_library(mylib src/b.c)
rosbuild_add_executable(mymain src/a.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mymain mylib)
```

---

I have not solved the problem with *ROS* **rosmake** yet. But I add the following lines in a makefile and use nomal **make** command and it works.

```
# The pre-processor options used by the cpp (man cpp for more).
CPPFLAGS  = -Wall -I/opt/ros/fuerte/include/

# The options used in linking as well as in any direct use of ld.
LDFLAGS   = -L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/ -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135176/how-to-rosmake-project-with-c-and-cpp?/) by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2014-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2014-03-03**:
those 3 cmake lines look OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(Long comment) First of all there seems to be a basic linker error, which is giving you the message about undefined functions. This means that no matter what make system you use, you're going to get the same error.  This is generic and not ROS-specific. I suggest looking at resources like [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958076/undefined-reference-to-function-error-in-c) first to nip this issue in the bud.

Once this is sorted  out, get a hang of how CMake works first.  I also suggest using Catkin to build instead of rosbuild, which uses rosmake. Then, go to [catkin](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin) docs to get an idea of how the catkin build tool works on ROS.

Keep in mind: the basic build system is the [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), on Unix and Linux systems. CMake is an abstraction that generates Makefiles. Catkin is yet another abstraction over CMake.

---

Originally posted by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) with karma: 365 on 2014-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1